# Using cases in a node in a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, cases

I am trying to put piece-wise functions into nodes in a Tikz diagram.
Using cases works fine in a Tikz node that is separate within a tikzpicture environment.
Putting the same node in a matrix breaks the use of & to divide a single line within the cases block.

Is there any way to get the output of the node inside the matrix to match that of the separate node?

[image: Differences between nodes]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, align=center]

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[block] (b1) {Separate node:\\
        \(
        u_{out}=
        \begin{cases}
        255 & \mbox{if } u_{in} > 255
        \end{cases}
        \)};

    \matrix[below=of b1] (m)
    {
        \node[block] (b2) {Node in matrix:\\
         \(
         u_{out}=
         \begin{cases}
         255 & \mbox{if } u_{in} > 255
         \end{cases}
         \)};\\
    };

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option `ampersand replacement` allows you to define which symbol to use instead of `&` in `matrix` environments. More detailed information in [20.5 Considerations Concerning Active Characters](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfmanual#page=313)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, align=center]

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[block] (b1) {Separate node:\\
        \(
        u_{out}=
        \begin{cases}
        255 & \mbox{if } u_{in} > 255
        \end{cases}
        \)};

    \matrix[below=of b1, ampersand replacement=\&] (m)
    {
        \node[block] (b2) {Node in matrix:\\
         \(
         u_{out}=
         \begin{cases}
         255 & \mbox{if } u_{in} > 255
         \end{cases}
         \)};\\
    };

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]